# CSS select all elements without span

Tags: html, css

This is an example of the html I have

```
<tbody class="list-item" style="">
<tr class="table-data">
    <td class="data">
      <span><a href="/example/100">data1</a></span>
    </td>
</tr>
</tbody>

<tbody class="list-item" style="">
<tr class="table-data">
    <td class="data">

    </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

As you can see, the second data class is empty. I need to select the empty element and hide it.

I would use the :empty selector, but I have whitespace in the html. I cannot edit the html or use javascript, only css.

I've tried many things but I just can't wrap my head around it. Can someone please help me here? Messy hacks/workarounds would be OK.

Edit: This is the CSS associated with it (sorry, I forgot this would be important)

```
[class='data'] {
font-size: 0;
display: block;
opacity: 0;
position: fixed;
width: 226px;
left: 100px;
bottom: 100px;
background-color: rgba(34,34,34,0.8);
border: 1px solid #333;
border-top: 0 !important;
transition: opacity 0.15s linear;
}

[class='data'] a {
color: #fff;
display: inline-block;
font-size: 9px;
height: 15px;
line-height: 15px;
margin-top: -1.5px;
max-width: 220px;
padding: 0 10px;
white-space: nowrap;
}

tr:hover [class='data'] {
background-color: rgba(34,34,34,0.8);
opacity: 1;
transition: 0.15s linear;
}
```

Comment: just td tags or div and a etc ... ?

Comment: can you just add a second class to the empty element?

Comment: I don't have control of the HTML, only CSS.

Comment: is there any other pattern associated with the structure??... do empty tds show up in a random sequence in you code, or they follow a pattern that we can use?

Comment: There aren't really any patterns. I have some tds with data, and some without data (temporarily). I need to hide the temporarily empty tds until data exists.

Answer (score 0):

for select not span in all of document use :

```
:not(span) {
    color: #ff0000;
}
```

if you want to select elements in td tags which have not span , use :

```
td:not(span) {
    color: #ff0000;
}
```

Comment: How would I make that more specific to the empty class? I tried `[class="data"]:not(span) {
    display: none;
}`  but that hides both of them.

Comment: you can use `:empty` selector , like `[class="data"]:empty{display:none}`

Comment: It's not empty though, it has whitespace I can't remove.

Comment: I dont know whay can not delete space , it was  my way to do it , good luck

Answer (score 0):

There is a property called `empty-cells: hide;` in CSS which hides the empty td even with whitespace.

```
<style>
table {
border-collapse: separate;
empty-cells: hide;
      } 
</style>
```

Refer This link for more info [Link](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_tab_empty-cells.asp)

Comment: I don't think that works for me because what I have isn't exactly a traditional table I think. I've added the CSS I'm using in the main post.

Answer (score 0):

try this below css where it will find for empty td cell and hide it

```css
.list-item>.table-data {
    border-collapse: separate;
    empty-cells: hide;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <tbody class="list-item" style="">
    <tr class="table-data">
      <td class="data">
        <span><a href="/example/100">data1</a></span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="table-data">
      <td class="data">

      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work with what I have. I edited my post to include the CSS I have associated with it. The problem is that the background color and border are still showing of the empty td when I hover over the tr.